# Update javascript variable in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html template.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        var chart;
        var chartData = [
            {
                "label": 2005,
                "data": 23.5
            },   
        ];
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 500px; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
```

How can i update chartData using php before actually  loading that (i am getting this template from db).

Comment: Please Provide Some Code.

Comment: Or at least, please show what you mean by adding an example of desired behavior to your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have added the html .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `echo` the variable into the script.

```
<?PHP
$var = "Hello world";
?>

<html>
<script>
var welcome = "<?php echo $var; ?>";
console.log(welcome);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: actually this is a predefined template. So i think i have to first find that variable and then update. I am not sure how to do that